# How to upgrade my Magento custom module to support in higher versions of php/Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-2.0

Apologies if my question is redundant or irrelevant. I am a PHP developer and I need to upgrade a custom Magento module to support in higher versions of Magento. I have made themes and plugins in WordPress but I am at the very beginning stage of Magento modules development. Currently, the plugin works totally fine in Magento 1.8.x and initial versions of Magento 1.9.x. But in any Magento installation that uses PHP version higher than 5.6.19, the plugin gives error during installation. I couldn't find any step by step guide to do this. Also please tell me do I need to create the custom module from scratch for Magento 2.
[here is the installation error in magento 1.9.3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgJgx.png)

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create the Magento 2 module largely from scratch. With regards the install errors on PHP 5.6.19+ - you're going to need to find the errors (probably in the error log) and see which part of your code is erroring. Once you've found the error logs in `var/logs` it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: show us the error

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response. Sorry for replying late. I have added the screen shot. I don't see php error here. How should I resolve it.?
@roman ,@thebluefox

Comment: your module has strong requirements of php version, as say @thebluefox you need to find where it is and replace it

Comment: I found the error log. It says "failed to open observer.php..." for so many files.